# windows 7 not loading after installing ubuntu 12.10

Tags: windows-7, 12.10

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 along side with windows. After restarting my laptop in grub it is showing 'windows 7(loader)' but an error is occurred while loading. My Ubuntu 12.10 is working great. Can any help me out with my problem.

Comment: Does it prompt any errors, or does it simply fail to load? If so, what does it display until it stops?

Comment: It shows error "A Disk read error occurred,press alt+ctrl+del to restart".

Comment: try `sudo update-grub` from a terminal?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It appears that either grub2, or the way Ubuntu implemented grub2, does not detect Windows partitions properly. I had a co-worker help me with this. First get grub working. Then I added the code below in `/etc/grub.d/08_custom`. Then `update-grub`. This puts Windows above Ubuntu so it will boot by default.

If you wish to boot Ubuntu by default, modify `40_custom` instead. This will create a new entry for Windows along with the useless entry that was originally found. Select the custom entry to boot Windows. My new `grub.cfg` is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/1368590/.

Here is the contents of my `08_custom`:

```
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry 'Windows 7 (customized entry)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    chainloader +1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the worst choice here if there's no other ways, put your windows installation disc into your computer, the boot from the disc. Then select the partition which Ubuntu is at, Delete them. Roboot and remove the disc, boot from hardrive, and according to my experience, there won't be Ubuntu Grub anymore.(Just for referance, might not work)

Answer (score 0):

1. Fix Windows via a Windows disk [this way](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader) until you get direct access to Windows.
2. Recover the GRUB menu via [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score -1):

Fixing the MBR gets windows to load for sure but GRUB disappears, then fixing GRUB gets Ubuntu to load but not windows and so on ...

Never get to a situation where both can boot peacefully from GRUB

Comment: ...is the wrong answer!